# Using FileHelpers to read CSV file from asp.net file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, filehelpers

I'm working on an ASP.NET Webforms C# application. I need to have a CSV file uploaded to server and contents read and saved to database. I read somewhere that [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) may be used for reading csv files but I haven't seen any example dealing with a HttpPostedFile. Anybody has any experience using filehelpers with file upload?

I'm open to alternative methods too. Thanks.

Comment: Closed as not a real question? What is a question then? I specifically asked for help using FileHelpers to read an uploaded CSV file. I got a 'REAL' answer to my 'REAL' Question. See below. If you don't understand what FileHelpers is, then just don't answer. Why downvote or close my question if you don't uderstand the subject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a sample to get you started.

```
using FileHelpers;

// First declare the record class

[Delimitedrecord("|")]
public class SampleType
{
    public string Field1;
    public int    Field2;
}


public void ReadExample(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(SampleType));

    SampleType[] records;    

    records = (SampleType[]) engine.ReadStream(
                         new StreamReader(file.InputStream), Int32.MaxValue);

    // Now "records" array contains all the records in the
    // uploaded file and can be acceded like this:

    int sum = records[0].Field2 + records[1].Field2;
}
```

Comment: You can use generics version too: 
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<SampleType>()  
to avoid the cast

Comment: nunespascal thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. MarcosMeli, I went ahead and used generics. Thanks all.

Comment: Hey guys, I see my question was closed as not a real question. You guys understood what I was asking and gave me real answers. If you think it should stay open for someone else in the future, I urge you to vote for reopening as someone else may your answers helpful. Thanks

Comment: Probably people voted for it to be closed because you didn't provide any code showing what you tried. Anyway, I voted for it to be reopened. Hope it helps someone in future.

Comment: how were you able to get the file passed to the controller? Can you post the HTML? I am using FileHelpers but cannot seem to get the file to pass into the controller.